# Find contacts that have been moved out of a group

Tags: custom-search

Working with Advanced Search and Search Builder but I can't figure out how to find contacts that were moved out of a group.

Civi version 4.7.1 on Drupal. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There IS a way to search for contacts removed from a group - but it's well-hidden.

- Go to **Contacts menu » Manage Groups**.
- Click the **Contacts** link next to the group you'd like to see deleted contacts for.
- Under *Group Status*, uncheck **Added** and check **Removed** before pressing **Search**.

[image]